# Soot plugin and command line - windows - jdk1.7

Tags: soot

I've created a simple plugin following the instructions found [here](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Creating-Soot-Plugins) and [here](http://blog.security-comprehension.org/?page_id=154).

However, when I launch Soot from command line I get an error (I also get a similar error when using the full path of the jars)

```
C:\..\folder>java -cp soot-2.5.0.jar;plugin.jar soot.Main --plugin plugin.xml -p jap.foo opt:true java.lang.Object

Invalid option -plugin Exception in thread "main" soot.CompilationDeathException: Option parse error
    at soot.Main.processCmdLine(Main.java:85)
    at soot.Main.run(Main.java:161)
    at soot.Main.main(Main.java:141)
```

What am I missing? Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using the [nightly build](https://soot-build.cs.uni-paderborn.de/nightly/soot/)